# Finding the angle between the radius and vector

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the angle between the radius vector produced and the tangent to the curve whose equation is $r = 4\cos\theta$ at the point where $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

My assumption was that I take the derivative, such that $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-4\sin\theta$. Then substitute in the value for $\theta$.

Though, this isn't the right answers, for I expect $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

I would appreciate your help, and if possible a pictorial example to help me understand this. The book i'm using is fairly terse and vague.

Answer (score 1):

As $\theta$ increases the point on the curve moves from $(4,0)$ to $(2,2)$ counterclockwise.

The tangent and the produced radius vector form an angle $=135^{\circ}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angle enclosed in a semicircle, other two for given condition are shown in isosceles right triangle.

Actually two correct answers. The angle radius vector makes to the outer tangent $\psi$ is $ 3 \pi/4$ but considering inner tangent it could be also $ \pi/4$ as shown... even with a consistent CCW convention.

The differential equation  determines the tangent. Its ode is $ \sin \psi =r/4 $. At the given radius, accordingly there are two arcsin $\psi$ values

[image]